# Codeigniter - Foreign Key

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, join, foreign-keys

I have two tables:

**ARTICLES**(article_id, article_title, article_text, article_date)

**COMMENTS**(comment_id, username, comment_text, comment_date, article_id)

I show each single article in **/read/id** in this way:

**Controller:**

```
public function read($id)
{ 
            $this->load->model('articles_model');

            $article_data['article'] = $this->articles_model->get_select_article($id);

            $this->load->view('header');

            $this->load->view('nav');

            $this->load->view('article-content', $article_data);

            $this->load->view('insert-comment');

            $this->load->view('footer');

}
```

**Model:**

```
public function get_select_article($id)
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('articles');
    $this->db->where('articles.article_id', $id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->row_array();
}
```

Now I want to insert comments for each article through this form:

**Insert-comment**

```
<div id ="insert-comment">
<h1>Insert comment</h1>
<?php 
echo form_open('????'); 
echo br(1);
echo form_label('Username', 'username');
echo br(1);
echo form_input('username');
echo br(1);
echo form_label('Text', 'comment_text');
echo br(1);
echo form_input('comment_text');
echo br(1);
echo form_submit('submit', 'Submit');
echo form_close();
?>
</div>
```

What I need in the model for insert the foreign key in relation to each single article?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need `article_id` while storing comment, as a foreign key. To do this, you will have to store it in a hidden field in the form, e.g.:

```
<input type="hidden" name="article_id" id="article_id" value="<?php echo $article_id; ?>" />
```

This way, you will be able to send article id along with comment info and store it into db.